# Inserting into Access database

Tags: java, database, ms-access

How do I resolve the error in inserting memo in Access from a Java program?

4159 the size of the string

the error

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]COUNT field incorrect
```

The source code that executes the insert statement:

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO webData VALUES ("+"'" + list.get(y)+"','"+data+ "')");
```

4159 the size of data

my schma is :

table name webData with 2 coulmun the

first ID of type text

the second Field1 of type memo

i have update the statment but i have get the same error:

> statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO webData (ID,Field1) VALUES ("+"'" + list.get(y)+"','"+data+ "')");

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please post your schema.

Rather than doing:

```
INSERT INTO webData VALUES (...)
```

You should be doing:

```
INSERT INTO webData (MyColumn1, MyColumn2) VALUES (...)
```

Do not rely on the physical column order in the table, you should state it explicitly to avoid errors.

Comment: thanks but it ives the same error                                       statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO webData (ID,Field1) VALUES ("+"'" + list.get(y)+"','"+data+ "')");

Comment: Apparently you didn't see our requests to post your schema.

Comment: i post it down its table name webData with 2 coulmun the first ID of type text the second Field1 of type memo

Comment: It's best to edit your question to add the schema. For one thing, comments are easy to miss--for another, you can format it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Does the comma have to be in speech marks and inverted commas?  You can simplify this, just a tip :).  But yes, post your DB scheme.

Comment: i have 2 column the first of type text the second of type memo  when i but small string in the second part it accept it